# Redirect from https://example.com to https://www.example.com

Tags: apache, ssl, mod-rewrite

I have below rules in apache config :

```
RewriteEngine  on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

this is working for below conditions :

example.com to https://www.example.com
www.example.com to https://www.example.com

but not working for :
https://example.com to https://www.example.com

What could be the issue? Any help please ? Thank you.

Comment: Please make clear what you mean with *"not working"*: no redirect, error message or warning in the browser ... ?

Comment: these directives are configured in the SSL virtual host ? in the default config file ?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich not working means, type "https://example.com " , loads website but I want it to redirect to "https://www.example.com".

Comment: @EugèneAdell in the web_example.conf

Comment: probably you need to add this rules in another config file, the one which contains the SSL virtual host.

Comment: In 000-default.conf file I have below lines :

    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/

Comment: @EugèneAdell i tried by adding in ssl config file as well but no solution, it works same.